# DBeaver ODBC connections

Tags: macos, odbc, unixodbc, dbeaver

I'm trying to connect to an ODBC data source from a Mac using DBeaver. I can't seem to find a way to set up an ODBC connection in DBeaver. Is it not supported? (JDBC is supported)

I'm trying to use the `FreeTDS` driver to connect to a MSSQL server. This server is on a different domain than the Mac so it cannot use Windows Authentication and hence the need to use an ODBC connection. I'm able to connect from the Mac using `tsql` which comes with FreeTDS.

Comment: I seem to vaguely recall that DBeaver supported ODBC back when Java_7 had the JDBC-ODBC Bridge, but when that was removed in Java_8 they dropped ODBC support. Have you tried using mssql-jdbc ("SQL Server" in DBeaver) or jTDS ("SQL Server (Old driver, jTDS)" in DBeaver)?

Comment: I just tried DBeaver on Xubuntu 18.04 and while the mssql-jdbc ("SQL Server") option was not available the jTDS option was. I logged in using the Windows credentials for `MY-DOMAIN\dr.evil` by specifying `dr.evil` as the "User name:" and setting `DOMAIN` to `MY-DOMAIN` on the "Driver properties" tab.

Comment: Awesome! Got it working. Thanks a lot. Was banging my head for couple of days on this!! Used the Authentication: Custom option and set the DOMAIN property

Comment: @GordThompson could you make an answer out of this, maybe a screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that DBeaver no longer supports ODBC connections, probably due to the fact that the JDBC-ODBC Bridge was removed from Java 8. However, in many cases the jTDS driver should suffice for connections to SQL Server instances from non-Windows machines. For example, in order to connect to a SQL Server instance using the Windows credentials for `GORD-HP\dr.evil` we can create a jTDS connection

[image]

enter the relevant information, noting that

1. the "Authentication" type is `NTLM`, and
2. the "User name" is just `dr.evil`

[image]

switch to the "Driver properties" tab and enter the `DOMAIN`

[image]

That should work, provided that the SQL Server instance has not disabled NTLM authentication.